# Cannot save because a value in column('WR#' is not allowed ( it is not in the list of legal values)

Tags: javascript, sql

On a web application, I am trying to create an order and save it, the system throws this error. What does this error means?

> Error: Cannot save because a value in column('WR#' is not allowed ( it is not in the list of legal values).

[image]

Comment: This is a place people ask Programming related questions, not for any general errors on some websites.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be very ambiguous.

Do you have any validation in your client side or you must have **data type** mis-match between the value you are trying to save and value which your table expects in db.